# How to get a semi-transparent border-image to show the border-color behind it?

Tags: html, css, colors, png, transparent

I have a wrapper div with a 20px right border. I set a border-color and then a border-image with a semi-transparent png.

I did that to be able to change the color below via JavaScript while keeping the texture of the png. But the "background" border color become white as soon as I use the border-image rule, or disappear at all.

The HTML is simply:

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
...
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    float: left; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    border-right: 20px solid lime url('../img/elastic.png'); 
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: To make it easier to test, could you create a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/)? You can upload your `elastic.png` to [http://imgur.com/](http://imgur.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but the `border-image` isn't meant to be used in conjunction with `border-color`.

According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-border-image):

> The 'border-image' property specifies an image to use **instead** of the border styles given by the 'border-style' properties.

As you can see with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/3wBCv/), any border style are ignored. Only the border-width have some effect.

I suggest you create specific images for each border you want.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could come up for your case is using an SVG in `border-image` that's encoded in a data: URI. This way, you can manipulate it via JS and apply the result.

Or, use a canvas element to dynamically generate a bitmap image, and use that as border-image.